# Create clone of text selection without use of clipboard

Tags: javascript, typescript

For my application I need a kind of internal clipboard with history.
I can't use the clipboard api (as far as I can see) as this would need permission from the user which is not an option.

I wan't to preserve formatting like bold, italics and strikethrough.

I was thinking about getting the content from window.getSelection(), but there is no way of easily cloning all the html that is in the selection.

The contents would need to go into another container element to be shown somewhere in the app.

Any ideas of how to achieve this are highly appreciated.

Best
Matthias

EDIT: I'm already interrupting the copy event and replace it with custom function. What I need to do is start at the anchorNode, cut some possible offset and go forward to the focusNode (also with offset). Also all unknown/unwanted tags (span, h1, div etc need to be removed but the text content shall stay). I hoped that someone has already done this or a similar task so I can save some time :/

Comment: There are two ways, as far as I can tell, that a user can copy text: through `CTRL+C` and `right click` -> `Copy`. You can probably use an event listener for the first, but you need to prevent the `right click` menu from popping-up and replace it with a custom one. If it doesn't fit your needs than you should relay on the clipboard API, even though it's not yet fully implemented in chrome and firefox.

Comment: I don't think there's a single API method that does this for you. Instead, you have to start at the anchor node and gather up nodes from it to the focus node. Definitely not trivial, but not all that bad. Some kind of "copy fragment" method would have been nice but I don't see one.

Comment: By browsing a bit on MDN I found the [`copy` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think that's what I need to do, I just thought someone must have done this before.

Comment: If the modifican happens to a css level, you might not be able to do it: waht if an element becomes bold thanks to its id? You won't be able to copy that element. What it can be done is that the main structure is copied, but you should also consider removing the `id`s... or at least append `_copy0` for example

Comment: I can be sure to have tags for the kinds of formatting I need to copy.

Comment: @DadiBit - Still a good observation though.

Comment: I'm testing the idea of testing `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.cloneNode(true)` and then removing non-selected text via `anchorNode.offset` and `focusNode.offset`. I need to do something similar in Waterfox Classic that does *not* have access to clipboard data. It seems promising and I'll keep this tab open.

Answer (score 0):

The [`copy` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event) could help you, as it doesn't require any permission to work.

```
var clipHistory = [];
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
    const selection = document.getSelection();
    clipHistory.push(selection.toString());
    event.preventDefault();      // optional, it prevents to modify the user's clipboard
});
// other functions can access clipHistory
```

A nice thing is that the `copy` event is very well supported.

Unlcukly this solution remove the formatting, but on way to keep it is to use a `<div contenteditable id="parse-div"></div>` and fire the `parse` event manually.

I found an intersting class: the `Range` one, but it doesn't allow to set a start and an end offset of non #text elements, as far I can undertand it.

Comment: yes I'm intercepting the event but I not only want to get the text from the selection (toString()), which is super easy, but text plus potential formatting like b, i, strike, strong.

Comment: @Tallerlei making the parse div `contenteditable` should keep the original formatting

Comment: No, it's just a string with the selected text unfortunately :(

Comment: The last four words of the title: `without use of clipboard`. I think you massively missed that.

Comment: @John As I already said in the comments of the question, the other way would be to prevent `CTRL+C` and the context menu. The OP actually wanted to avoid asking user clipboard permission, which actually is not a problem with the `'copy'` event.